# One-to-many list items in trigger-response model

Tags: lists, info-visualisation

I have an app for a content item that can include triggers and responses, created by the user.

Users can associate many triggers to one single response (many-to-one) or they can have each trigger associated with a different response, or they can have any combination of this (i.e. two triggers map to one response, another trigger maps to a different response).

I'm currently designing the content item details page, where the user should be able to get a high level view of which triggers and responses are available within his content item.

I would love to present this info graphically - i.e. include some sort of visual representation of the trigger-response model (sort of graph-like/map). However, since I cannot foresee how many triggers will be included for one response, this can create a very "dense" and "noisy" map visually, and I'd like to keep it simple, clean, clear...

Are there any proposals on how to manage such a thing or any references for this kind of situation in other apps? I've been trying hard to find other apps with the same model so I can learn from but was not successful.

I created a mockup of what I thought could I could do visually (note the little arrow is for a menu, I need a sub-menu on each element, this is not just a drawing - not a simple dashboard graph), but bear in mind the triggers list can be very long, and then, this view will not work (too many arrows, too little room to understand).

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions or is familiar with similar examples?

Comment: Are there any situations in which a trigger could lead to multiple responses, or is this strictly a X-to-one setup?

Comment: Strictly X-to-one setup

Answer (score 1):

I would look into something like:

[image]

Possibly color-coded and playing with blank spaces.